# Cannot read data from serial port from Ubuntu guest on a OSX host

Tags: macos, ubuntu, serial-port, virtual-machine, pipe

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox on a OSX Mavericks host. I am trying to read data from Arduino through serial port. I enabled port 1 in vm, the setting is:
Port Number: COM1  IRQ:4   I/O Port: 0x3F8   Port Mode: Dis connected. Create Pipe(unticked) Port/File Path: /dev/tty.submodem1411

In the virtual machine, the port can be found. When I use setserial trying to find the ports, the output is:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

Although the port can be found, it does not getting data data from the serial port. I've read the manual for virtualBox and understand this is happening because I un-ticked the port mode is disconnected. However, I really don't know how to set up the file path properly if select Host Device or Host Pipe. 
The Arduino serial port is called     `tty.submodem1411` in the host system. What I've tried are:
1) select Host Pipe and tick the Create Pipe and set File Path as     `/dev/tty.submodem1411` or     `/dev/ttyS0`. However, the virtual can not start （It stops responding and there's nothing I can do but force quit it）
2) select Host device and set File Path as     `/dev/tty.submodem1411` or     `/dev/ttyS0`, in this case the 'Create pipe' is greyed out. When I try to start the vm, a status bar shows up along with text"starting virtual machine" but it lost responding as well and the machine cannot be opened this way.

I've installed the pipe on the host system but don't know how can I create a connection between the virtual machine and host system. Rally appreciate if anyone can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the exact OS setup as you do (Ubuntu 12.04 running in a VirtualBox VM on Mavericks), but I ran into the VM freezing with the 'Starting virtual machine...' message while using a TI Tiva C Series LaunchPad (similar to the Arduino Uno). To solve this particular problem:

1. Connect the device and turn it on *before* you run the VM. This will create the USB device in /dev (in your case /dev/tty.submodem1411).
2. In `VM Settings` > `Ports` > `Serial Ports` > `Port 1`, check `Enable Serial Port`, choose `COM1` as the `Port Number`, choose `Host Device` as the `Port Mode`, and enter the path to your USB device in `Port/File Path`.
3. Workaround to VM getting stuck at 'Starting virtual machine...': Run a serial port communication program such as minicom and configure it to use /dev/tty.submodem1411. Then have it send the initialization string to the device ('initialize Modem' in minicom). If this configuration is saved, all you need to do is run minicom - it will automatically initialize the device on startup.
4. Run the VM. The guest OS will now boot (thanks to Step 3 - this seems to be a VirtualBox bug). The serial port in the guest OS is now /dev/ttyS0.

But:

The following may not be relevant to the Arduino, but FWIW, this is what I did to program the LaunchPad: In `VM Settings` > `Ports` > `USB`, check `Enable USB Controller` and click on `Add Filter From Device` and select your device. When you boot the guest OS, if the device is already on, you will not be able to access it (your device will not be checked in the VirtualBox VM menu item `Devices` > `USB Devices`). Just power cycle the board (or unplug/plug in) and guest OS would now have access to the device (the device will be checked in the aforementioned menu). A new serial device is created now (in my case, called /dev/ttyACM0) which can be used for communication with the board. If you do this, you don't need the serial port setup of Step 2 (and hence, no need for the workaround of Step 3). If you do keep Steps 2 and 3, you should be able to communicate with the device using both /dev/ttyS0 and /dev/ttyACM0. Hope this helps.